# How to get object from Array where type="text"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops

I want to extract the groups that have `text` from this array. The array can contain groups which include `text` and some other groups.

E.g:

```
[
    {
        "index": 3,
        "uid": "188960ecb29_00562b0c",
        "x": 18.651406278454424,
        "y": 44.14920570161545,
        "width": 180.14783325004774,
        "height": 53.336747638012184,
        "items": [
            {
                "uid": "18895f59b1a_2c5a5c7a",
                "locked": false,
                "rotation": 0,
                "type": "text",
                "text": [
                    "abc"
                ],
                "x": 154.37927087307924,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 25.768562376968507,
                "height": 20.90412770669292,
                "sampleTextChanged": true,
                "fontSize": 15.590551181102365,
                "fontFamily": "NimbusSansME",
                "textBold": false,
                "textItalic": false,
                "textUnderline": false,
                "textAlignment": "TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT",
                "textLetterSpacing": 0,
                "textLineSpacing": 1,
                "color": {
                    "red": 0,
                    "green": 0,
                    "blue": 0,
                    "__class__": "RGBAColor",
                    "alpha": 1
                },
                "placeholderText": [
                    "Text"
                ],
                "isPlaceholderTextActive": false,
                "translationKey": "",
                "newPathCalculation": true,
                "shadow": {
                    "blur": 0,
                    "color": "{\"red\":255,\"green\":255,\"blue\":255,\"transparent\":0}",
                    "coords": {
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0
                    },
                    "distance": 0,
                    "opacity": 1
                },
                "index": 0,
                "originalTextItem": [
                    "abc"
                ],
                "originalXcoords": [
                    [
                        0,
                        8.25203001968504,
                        17.47085691437008,
                        25.768562376968507
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "index": 1,
                "uid": "1889607cfdf_091e59ca",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 32.432619931319266,
                "width": 22.175427534448822,
                "height": 20.90412770669292,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "uid": "18895ecc7c7_2d5440b6",
                        "locked": false,
                        "rotation": 0,
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": [
                            "xyz"
                        ],
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 22.175427534448822,
                        "height": 20.90412770669292,
                        "sampleTextChanged": true,
                        "fontSize": 15.590551181102365,
                        "fontFamily": "NimbusSansME",
                        "textBold": false,
                        "textItalic": false,
                        "textUnderline": false,
                        "textAlignment": "TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT",
                        "textLetterSpacing": 0,
                        "textLineSpacing": 1,
                        "color": {
                            "red": 0,
                            "green": 0,
                            "blue": 0,
                            "__class__": "RGBAColor",
                            "alpha": 1
                        },
                        "placeholderText": [
                            "Text"
                        ],
                        "isPlaceholderTextActive": false,
                        "translationKey": "",
                        "newPathCalculation": true,
                        "shadow": {
                            "blur": 0,
                            "color": "{\"red\":255,\"green\":255,\"blue\":255,\"transparent\":0}",
                            "coords": {
                                "x": 0,
                                "y": 0
                            },
                            "distance": 0,
                            "opacity": 1
                        },
                        "index": 0,
                        "originalTextItem": [
                            "xyz"
                        ],
                        "originalXcoords": [
                            [
                                0,
                                7.54406065452756,
                                14.95870755413386,
                                22.175427534448822
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "type": "group",
                "rotation": 0
            },
            {
                "index": 2,
                "uid": "188960e945c_35ab99fa",
                "x": 44.108363106593984,
                "y": 15.56765756703328,
                "width": 56.72123163199389,
                "height": 35.17448047647336,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "uid": "18896072844_1298562b",
                        "locked": false,
                        "rotation": 0,
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": [
                            "group"
                        ],
                        "x": 15.567657567033265,
                        "y": 14.270352769780445,
                        "width": 41.15357406496064,
                        "height": 20.90412770669292,
                        "sampleTextChanged": true,
                        "fontSize": 15.590551181102365,
                        "fontFamily": "NimbusSansME",
                        "textBold": false,
                        "textItalic": false,
                        "textUnderline": false,
                        "textAlignment": "TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT",
                        "textLetterSpacing": 0,
                        "textLineSpacing": 1,
                        "color": {
                            "red": 0,
                            "green": 0,
                            "blue": 0,
                            "__class__": "RGBAColor",
                            "alpha": 1
                        },
                        "placeholderText": [
                            "Text"
                        ],
                        "isPlaceholderTextActive": false,
                        "translationKey": "",
                        "newPathCalculation": true,
                        "shadow": {
                            "blur": 0,
                            "color": "{\"red\":255,\"green\":255,\"blue\":255,\"transparent\":0}",
                            "coords": {
                                "x": 0,
                                "y": 0
                            },
                            "distance": 0,
                            "opacity": 1
                        },
                        "originalTextItem": [
                            "group"
                        ],
                        "originalXcoords": [
                            [
                                0,
                                9.013287401574805,
                                14.342089074803152,
                                23.241187869094492,
                                31.9195220226378,
                                41.15357406496064
                            ]
                        ],
                        "index": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "index": 3,
                        "uid": "188960e5f49_2341c362",
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 29.803226500984252,
                        "height": 20.90412770669292,
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "uid": "188958badfe_3a73220b",
                                "locked": false,
                                "rotation": 0,
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": [
                                    "Text"
                                ],
                                "x": 0,
                                "y": 0,
                                "width": 29.803226500984255,
                                "height": 20.90412770669292,
                                "sampleTextChanged": false,
                                "fontSize": 15.590551181102365,
                                "fontFamily": "NimbusSansME",
                                "textBold": false,
                                "textItalic": false,
                                "textUnderline": false,
                                "textAlignment": "TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT",
                                "textLetterSpacing": 0,
                                "textLineSpacing": 1,
                                "color": {
                                    "red": 0,
                                    "green": 0,
                                    "blue": 0,
                                    "__class__": "RGBAColor",
                                    "alpha": 1
                                },
                                "placeholderText": [
                                    "Text"
                                ],
                                "isPlaceholderTextActive": false,
                                "translationKey": "",
                                "newPathCalculation": true,
                                "shadow": {
                                    "blur": 0,
                                    "color": "{\"red\":255,\"green\":255,\"blue\":255,\"transparent\":0}",
                                    "coords": {
                                        "x": 0,
                                        "y": 0
                                    },
                                    "distance": 0,
                                    "opacity": 1
                                },
                                "index": 0,
                                "istextCircularMode": false,
                                "originalTextItem": [
                                    "Text"
                                ],
                                "originalXcoords": [
                                    [
                                        0,
                                        9.119863435039372,
                                        17.60027066929134,
                                        25.1443313238189,
                                        29.803226500984255
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "group",
                        "rotation": 0
                    }
                ],
                "type": "group",
                "rotation": 0
            }
        ],
        "type": "group",
        "rotation": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Please include the array as a code snippet and fix the quote errors in it

Comment: [array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: do you want an array of `type="text"`?

Comment: @safir If I'm not mistaken there are nested items

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0xMDm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame yes its works . do u have some simple solution ? 
I need type="text" dynamically even if its nested complex groups.

Comment: It is already supporting nested groups. It's the most simplest and the best in terms of time complexity

Comment: should I write an answer where I will explain the algorithm?

Comment: @wonderflame yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't have type safety, since it's not what the OP is about.

Algorithm:

- Create a stack and populate it with the items on the first level
- While the stack is not empty:

  - Pop the last element from the stack
  - If the popped element has the desired type:

    - Pushed the element into the result array
  - Push children of the popped element into the stack to ensure visiting all items
- Return result array

Implementation:

```
const data = [];
const getSpecificType = (type: string) => {
  const result: Record<string, any>[] = [];

  const stack: Record<string, any>[] = [...data];

  while (stack.length) {
    const current = stack.pop();

    if (!current) continue;
    if (current.type === type) {
      result.push(current);
    }
    stack.push(...(current.items ?? []));
  }

  return result;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAsAKBjAb133wEsw4BTADwC4YBmAGmJIFdS56ByARgA5+ATgBsABkrAARgCYhAfTFiArCJlSxwbizwk6MAQDoRy3gBYxagOz8zys2ZlmdJGAE96Dw+aEyVVsV4RXntlFxIAd04oAAt6ATFvMxsGBhllJWSrZ1Z8GMpSAHMYqHplBkNUkWyrEQZ+QJkBHN0yKEoAWwh6bFaSIj7XDi4YPkEhZQAzZSEpXgR5GWBlBGVgKwRtXNcYABsQYABrShHJhF2ISnCdmAAnEGQoUnB6MWudqDcAB0oeduooFtBiR-qVMNwEFItABdd6ufQhMyVKy+AL8KwMMQopxwkgeGBvbauKJwWL0dKGWr8VQyBi1UTUrG4vIFYpgvyGIRiMy8GRWAIiES+XzMmAQBAdL67SgAFRoUAAwjEEGBCid6FBbmwrkSSJNwFAAMqkABevwMykMMxUpgEvF4YlpJlF+rAUAAYhLSLt8dwAHKkDpSNgQQ0qiAAWQAokCbvhQQAhEC7U7nS6i0EASWQu1IwHoZwuOuB8flAFUKJRbrmwObC+ndaWAQBBXOFMAdShungyqMADRl8mbABlMwBxP3yYdR90y2Nx0HDyhQdq3Q1fBDAciFV4Z+XD8iUdeb7fxUWgfa3egDOMkW7qgmi-CFe9d3eNkhSXba98lkjAXYEAgbpRgAJTHBNmwVZMQFuedb3OL5lTPD8AF9RSlTdKBiZMqFuOUAR6bgCMBWEP1ICAAAVAOAbDcKrEjm2AJ4ADc6zTYtb01cNAKecAAGlKF9eCdlrCJKKQGIFXOYA2F454wA1LVOLjCBlTgEAImvD98C-Ngr0fHSYAvWD6AAIgIbh7zgbhaHSMJuBfSgu1s+ymG4PTKFc5QHO4yAN3vN1bLEVCzKfYyQFguAQIIGB9DedxXhgdCjLgCjkDAWjf1vfAQA3LdPhQv8Ur-cgqHi0VYKKchzhI7NOiIyEYUq25qrAc4+1AKKQN6HLMAS-hDHSPxMUCBkMmcAwrEMZIxGpIVzDpJR+CYGAKSpGk6SFERGSsMi-32m4SpuG84zKmgitvYYeAEYRxCsYBJjgSZFCEXhKBmYBNlFCqP3xNIZrSYIhCEBheDB3xBVFEkyTWmRvCsew+XKBwzEEGQZFFfIihKclEi5Hk+QFIU5Ex8j2i6HojNOvrrtGW6JkkdZ1kWOB7AsKQRBE299iOB96xUvr7keBTsr6mBPh+P55W5hd5SI6g3BNbhDvF36-1cfFCQ1yJojiOGEaRxGGFR9GyZ1lkcfZfHuV5flLBJkUjPwcVJWlEilRVNURk1bVwvwV0jVNc0QitLkfPtfh7UdBhnWdmBA89DpvV9AMgxDMNIGjWWbkTXCCw4-2JflbNzjzAuiyL0EKzwmt2Mr+PQVbIoOy7MFiP7QcR3HSdp1nHOPn3ZdV2PLdVTFvrF0PUfTwMIuTIMmnxesifxact9DItz9v3NbXxf-QDgJ4cDIOgy8B5uRDkLn+PjvFzDaJwlMGPl8ESJVouKOorCn7wxjmNIGxCuDYt5+QgPJASQkeAXxIGJCSsRpK7FkhAxSEtlJFzUggDSWlCDx10t+Aye994RUvOZSy1lvIOXXmASh7lPK0O4GAgKbdgqhSLvgLqtxorXjiruRKBJkrsPgOlFUWVN7EJgHlE8hUb5bzvn1c66t95VUKDVXYdUKYKyVh-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-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-A3qtsSOod2-egafUSJDUfMCEFI3n2qzG3YSE40HcK0x28ybf4v0+Rm9+gWc3f0fvRNNLYAFAMG3K8W5a3OVugdVmtCCZJyTc0pZtE3W2aXbd1zthDXskNMjACy-abKjqoX64dO8GETqnawudJ2IpPqXRVVd66WeboymI87xC90bIPc5n7Z06NXZyulWlpBbj1tuBGEAVBxvdZPbVc9HQiLA+q6r3Yj6jG6YJ71An77VqfvtE0uoZgSk9NBlYGDXjjBKGheluQ4NJoUnMFbsGaR6gCCEMT-AchDAyei-JuLblnP4BBzcaPJBRdR6ri8ng3zflF3uUk-nrgmPUc86MFPcTRTp8bfz0JwTc-RJ+QX7YRf3O6BKtCAA3LgXAoBICwDVEaH4W5Jh5hlC8tAMAAAUufoCtVVAASjQAAPmOxw8A0A7iUAgHJMEoFJBRQADyj+3KtFUbgp8YGhAPw-TecCsFbwvrdRx6Br9AFwrfmod8wD3wfo-6AMCGE-4gZAjfm+6AiDEN6JQEPlfocIYNKKqLEJPkvBfrALJLcFOgPqAYYF8HlIPuPqftsKQJMEPgAITwFTqT6t5PBgDain4ZI4GD4EFtyGCRJoCoDoCRLQG6j3jL67BQAoEhgxBUH6SEHkFx7bDIFfBcGD6f6GA8EIE0EbKdAQAwAAD8chmA0I4+GBrAqEf+p2y4+kYAi+bBUAp+qEmBOAF+yYlA4BIAhQg+He64kg2BveLyg+jCMsKhp+QAA)

An alternative solution would be a recursive approach, however, it requires additional memory for the recursive invocation